# Caliburn Micro subscribe to onpropertychanged event from view code behind

Tags: silverlight, mvvm, caliburn.micro

I'm working on a silverlight project that has a file viewer.  This file viewer does not have a Source property or other property that accepts a stream.  It does have a LoadDocument(Stream file) method.  Since the file will be loaded asynchronously I need to "Notify" the view that the buffer is available and then let the View call the LoadDocument method.

In MVVMLight I could do this with the "Messenger" functionality.  I see the EventAggregator but everything I see has the communications going the other way.  I feel like this should be really easy to do but I just don't see it.

Is there a way in the Views constructor to bind a method to a property of the ViewModel?  It seems to be this is the same functionality that is done in xaml I just want to do it in the code behind.

Thanks

dbl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure by the post but it sounds like you want to bind an event from a control to a method on your view

In that case:

```
<SomeControl cal:Message.Attach="[Event SomeEvent] = [Action SomeMethod($eventArgs)]" />
```

If it's the other way round you can either use the event aggregator (the view can subscribe to events... why not, it's decoupled still...)

VM:

```
SomeEventAggregator.Publish(new SomeMessageInstanceThatTheViewWillSubscribeTo());
```

View:

```
class SomeView : UserControl, IHandle<SomeMessageInstanceThatTheViewWillSubscribeTo>

// dont forget to...
SomeEventAggregator.Subscribe(this);
```

Alternatively - implement an interface on the view

```
class SomeView : UserControl, IAcceptSomeNotificationMessage
{
    public void Notify() { // blah
    }
}
```

VM:

```
class SomeViewModel : Screen // whatever 
{
    void SomeMethod() 
    {
        // The VM should be IViewAware so will implement GetView()
        var view = GetView();

        if(view is IAcceptSomeNotificationMessage)
            (view as IAcceptSomeNotificationMessage).Notify();
    }
}
```

Pick one of the above - I'm sure there are more ways. I usually use an event aggregator - of course it depends on how much IoC you are using and how decoupled everything is.

Comment: Thanks, ended up I handled it a little differently.  I subclassed the control and added a Dependency property property on that control and used that on my form.  In the property changed event I then called the base method that needed to be called.  It was a more elegant solution in this situation.  But thanks for the answers.